# I'm reading SICP and trying to follow along, but why do the Lisp interpreters I find online fail with the DEFINE keyword?

Tags: lisp, sicp

This is the book...

http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html

Any idea which interpreter I should use to work with the code presented here?

So far I have tried a few online and download Lisp interpreters and all I get is errors when I try to use DEFINE.

Example:

From this section: http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%_sec_1.1

Put in here: http://www.ugcs.caltech.edu/~rona/tlisp/

```
> (define (square x) (* x x))
*** EVAL Error: Function 'DEFINE' is not defined. ***
```

Also tried with 'lispbox' with similar results.

Ah HA: http://sisc-scheme.org/sisc-online.php works, thanks for the tip blabla999, will accept answer soon.

Upon further research: **Scheme != Common Lisp**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

probably because:

(EQ Scheme CommonLisp) -> #f

and also:

(EQ Scheme ManyOtherLisps) -> #f

try a real scheme (I recommand plt, which has been renamed to Racket, recently).
(Or write your own - see http://www.avc-cvut.cz/avc.php?id=9769)

Comment: Confusion level increased by 100%. What does this mean? Wait... are you saying that they are not equal? So 'Scheme' is a specific flavor of Lisp?

Comment: Scheme is a Lisp-derived language, but Common Lisp is the most typical thing called “Lisp” out there, today (give or take). Lisp = ancestral language / language family; Scheme = one descendant / member of family; Common Lisp = what (most?) people mean by “Lisp” when referring to a singular language

Comment: (eq 'common-lisp 'clos) -> NIL  &  (part-of 'clos 'common-lisp) -> T

Comment: Actually, nowadays I would even say: Lisp is the syntax, and as such the common thing among all of them. Scheme and CL (and others) define concrete (and actually quite different) semantics.

Comment: @blabla999, CLOS is short for Common Lisp Object System, the OOP subsystem of Common Lisp. The programming language is called Common Lisp. Its abbreviation is CL.

Comment: @rainer: ;-) [ but why are you comparing names and not the things?)

Comment: @blabla999, because in Lisp the symbols refer to the things. The value of CLOS and Scheme are again only another representation, another indirection.

Comment: Depends on the environment, in which you eval - right ?
So, (equal 'chicken 'ironScheme) -> #f,
but (equal chicken ironScheme) -> #t
(well, not quite, but you get my point...)

Answer (score 1):

There is a great many different dialects of Lisp, of which Common Lisp is perhaps the most used today. Scheme, with which you are familiar, does not claim to be a Lisp, although it shares many characteristics.

For what it's worth, what you are trying to do is written

```
(defun square (x) (* x x))
```

in Common Lisp.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way (by far) I have found to get a Lisp environment for the examples in SCIP is to use DrRacket in Racket found here http://racket-lang.org/

The DrRacket environment has an editor and REPL that supports copy/paste and pretty print much like the Python Idle tool.  It is simple to install and works with all of the examples from the book and [the videos](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures/1a-overview-and-introduction-to-lisp).

I found this other great hints on learning lisp here: http://www.learningclojure.com/2011/02/advice-to-newbie.html